# Java data structure for optimized get and iterate from then on

Tags: java, data-structures, treeset

I need a data structure to do a get / find in Log N time and iterate starting from the object that was returned by the get operation. The iterator should iterate in the same order in which elements are inserted into the data structure.

Can I achieve this using TreeSet ? Or any other data structure?

Thanks!

Comment: get/find based on what criteria? This looks like a case for an array and binary search really.

Comment: [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) could save your day if you have a key for the objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with a `SortedMap<Integer, Object>` and use keys for keeping track of the insertion order, you'll be able to use the fast `tailMap` operation for your needs.

If you need to find the position of an object by a key (or maybe by the object itself), then introduce another `WeakHashMap<Object, Integer>` that will map from your key to the position of the object. You'll then use the retrieved sequence number as the key into the former map.

Comment: A map with insertion sequence numbers as keys and actual objects as values will not provide logarithmic time get / find as the OP required.

Comment: @MvG [The Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) proves you wrong.

Comment: OK, it depends on *what* you want to find things by, but I had assumed that the OP wahts to find by *value*, not by *sequence number*. [containsValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsValue%28java.lang.Object%29) at least explicitely warns about linear complexity. If you have different information about *find by value* complexity, please provide a link.

Comment: @MvG I see you are in fact correct. Yesterday when I was answering this, I was convinced the request was to start by the sequence number.

Comment: @MvG I added another sentence, I think it is a fine idea.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you want to get / find items *by value*, as opposed to access by *insertion sequence number*. I assume that this value is completely unrelated to the order in which items are inserted.

The closest you can get with standard Java foundation classes is a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). This allows fast searching and iteration in insertion order. But it does not give you an iterator starting at a given position, so you'll have to implement that yourself. Either based on the `LinkedHashSet`, or using your own set implementation. I guess the easiest way would be using a `HashSet` and implementing the linking yourself. That way, you could use the set methods to look up the starting element, and use that to construct an iterator following the links. You could hide the links inside a wrapper object, so you won't have to expose them in your API.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are using Java 6, you can have a look at [ConcurrentSkipListSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) and [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).

Comment: True - I'm sorry to have missed that!